# Can someone help me with the heat equation with a time dependent source?

Tags: heat-equation

It's one dimensional. 0 ≤ x ≤ π

u_t = u_xx + t^2 e^-t

BC: -u_x = u/2 for both ends

IC: u(0,x) = 0

I already determined the eigenvalues but I can't proceed. And what if the source is te^-t x instead?

Comment: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/pde/heat/Heat-Duhamel.pdf